# Is there any way of starting a clustering algorithm (hclust) on a database that already is clustered?

Tags: r, hierarchical-clustering, hclust

I have a database (df) that is already clustered (Class) but I want to further group together those clusters with a hierarchical algorithm. I tried using "member" in the function hclust() but it keeps rebuilding the tree entirely

```
dendo <- hclust(vegdist(df, method = "euclidean"), method = "ward.D2", members = Class)
plot(dendo, labels = Class)
```

This gives me this tree, but I was hoping each label already grouped together (eg: all the "17" labels in one single leave or starting in the same branch):

Dendogram

[image]

To be clear, I'm not looking to re-order the branches but restart the clustering from a pre-set of clusters.

Comment: Use `aggregate` to compute the mean values for each variable in your clustered data and then run `hclust` on the aggregated data. Use the `members=` argument to indicate how many observations each of your pre-defined clusters has. See the Details section of the `hclust` manual page and the example using the `USArrests` data set.

Comment: Thank you so much. I read the details section of ```hclust``` but completely misunderstood the use of ```members```. Now I do and ```aggregate``` worked.